# Why the current flows only through those conductors which are next to the one below the magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

Hi,
I´ve been looking at the working principle for the squirrel cage rotor and I end up with a doubt about what physically happens when a magnet is move at a certain velocity above a ladder with conductors shortcircuit by two bars A and B. I quietly understand the principle of the induction motors but I get very confused and don´t find a reason on  why does the current flows only on those conductors which are next to the one below the magnet (as it can be seen in the picture). I think it´s more convincing that It has to flow through all of them.

Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current does flow in the other bars and the sum of those (return) currents is equal to the current which flows in the bar under the magnet.
The person who first produced the diagram probably showed just two return currents to make the diagram clearer.